# How do I write subqueries in MYSQL to link columns from multiple databases?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table named Booking_tbl:

```
+-----------+---------+----------+
| BookingId | ClassId | UserName |
+-----------+---------+----------+
|         1 |       6 | Student1 |
|         2 |       6 | Student2 |
|         3 |       6 | Student3 |
|         4 |       6 | Student4 |
|         5 |       3 | Student5 |
|         6 |       4 | Student4 |
|         7 |       5 | Student3 |
|         8 |       6 | Student2 |
+-----------+---------+----------+
```

I also have this table named Class_tbl:

```
+---------+------------+
| ClassId | ClassLimit |
+---------+------------+
|       1 |         57 |
|       2 |          3 |
|       3 |         43 |
|       4 |         34 |
|       5 |          5 |
|       6 |          3 |
+---------+------------+
```

I want to be able to write an SQL statement that returns all the classId's in which the booking limit has not been met. Since the booking table does not contain the class limit, I am unsure on how I can make this work. I have heard about sub queries, but do not know how to use them. I have this so for.

```
SELECT ClassId,
IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Booking_tbl WHERE ClassId = 3)<
(SELECT ClassLimit FROM Class_tbl WHERE ClassId = 3),
'true','false') AS "TRUE/FALSE"
FROM Class_tbl WHERE ClassId = 3;
```

I don't know how to make this into a query whose result will give me a list of all the classId's whose limit is not yet reached.

Comment: Correlated subquery much?

Comment: @g.d.d.c Nope. Don't know about subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with sub query as:

```
SELECT c.ClassId
FROM class_tbl as c
LEFT JOIN(SELECT class_tb.ClassId, COUNT(Booking_tbl.ClassId) as total_booked
          FROM class_tbl
          LEFT JOIN Booking_tbl on class_tbl.ClassId=Booking_tbl.ClassId
          GROUP BY class_tbl.ClassId) as b ON b.ClassId = c.ClassId
WHERE c.ClassLimit > total_booked
```

Comment: I get this error when trying to run this: `[42S22][1054] Unknown column 'b.ClassId' in 'on clause'`

Comment: One more thing, if there are no bookings for a class, it doesn't show it. It only returns classId's who have some bookings. For example, when I run this on my data I get 3,4, and 5 instead of 1,2,3,4, and 5.

Comment: Do you know of a way that would select from class table instead of from booking table, since all classes are in class_tbl but not all classes are in booking_tbl?

Comment: @Rixwaan See this updated code to fetch all class details